# How to auto adjust the height of one element as per amount of text in the textbox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a simple layout with a float element and some text for some article. The left-hand side should display the item number in a float box and right side the item description.

I want to set the height of float element as per the amount of text in the description. How to achieve that?

The HTML code is like below.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 0; 
display: -ms-flexbox;">

<div style="float: left; background-color: #f73738; color: yellow;
 font-size: 20px; min-width: 48px; text-align: center; padding: 40px 0; 
height : ?">1</div>

<h2 style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 20px; padding: 20px 0 
20px 12px; margin: 0; text-align: center;"> Some demo text to be entered
 here. The item should be described in detail.</h2>
</div>
```

I want something so that the height of float can be self-adjusted with the amount of text. So basically I am looking for the value of height. The amount of text will keep changing, so will be the height of it. How to make sure the item number has the same height as item description.

Currently, I get something like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etjn8.png)

Can you help me to changes the CSS ( style elements) so that it can auto adjust with the text?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is incomplete. You're only applying the IE attribute for flexbox. Change `display: -ms-flexbox;` to `display: flex`. Is this what you wanted?

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 0; display: flex">

  <div style="float: left; background-color: #f73738; color: yellow; font-size: 20px; min-width: 48px; text-align: center; padding: 40px 0;">1</div>

  <h2 style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 20px; padding: 20px 0 20px 12px; margin: 0; text-align: center;"> Some demo text to be entered here. The item should be described in detail.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I am looking for the height of the float element so that it can auto set to the height of the border element.

Comment: @user1535460 I'm sorry, I don't understand. Currently, like you can see if you press "Run code snippet" in my answer, the element with the float attribute has the same height as the container element with the border attribute. Can you please add an image which shows the result you want?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. your solution worked for me.

Comment: @user1535460 I'm glad my solution helped. If your question is answered, please [close your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.